# HTTP to HTTPS redirect using .htaccess file not working

Tags: .htaccess, http, https, server, http-status-code-301

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 https://whatmovieshouldiwatchtoday.com/error404.php

php_flag display_errors 1

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?movie/([0-9A-Za-z-:-]+)/?$ /movie.php?id=$1 [NC,L] 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?cast/([0-9A-Za-z-:-]+)/?$ /cast.php?cast=$1 [NC,L] 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?keyword/([0-9A-Za-z-:-]+)/?$ /keyword.php?keyword=$1 [NC,L]
```

This is my code, now this part of the code is supposed to redirect HTTP to https, but it is not working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

When I try to open my website (even with https),  Google chrome shows "Waiting For Whatmovieshouldiwatchtoday.com" and after few seconds, it shows

> This page isn’t working
>
> whatmovieshouldiwatchtoday.com redirected you too many times.
>
> Try clearing your cookies.
>
> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Those three lines look fine, I assume there is some other piece that redirects from https to http... Pplease use your browsers console to verify the actual redirections you receive back.